# Amazon Echo: Visualize temperature on external website

Tags: sensors, alexa-skills-kit

The Amazon Echo has a temperature sensor inside. Now I'd like to visualize the temperature profile on my website. Furthermore I have a two other temperature sensors connected to the Echo, which I would also like to visualize.
Is there any easy way to do this?

I searched for Alexa Skills for this. But I have not yet found anything.
I could try to create an own skill for this. But for this a small example would be helpful, and I have not yet found one.
Isn't there any smart home service, which provides such a functionality?
If not, I also could run my own server, which polls the temperature regularly or receives the temperature from the Echo.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no public interface available for skills to query the temperature of the echo sensor. For skills there is only the other way round to provide the temperature of a controlled sensor to Alexa via the [Alexa.TemperatureSensor Interface](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-temperaturesensor.html)

Since the Alexa App is presenting the temperature of the sensor on a view, there must be a private interface.

While the temperature is only one function the app (and previously the corresponding website) made available remotely, there have been already other projects, which reverse engineered most of those interfaces - starting with a [blogpost](https://blog.loetzimmer.de/2017/10/amazon-alexa-hort-auf-die-shell-echo.html) creating a [shell script](https://loetzimmer.de/patches/alexa_remote_control.sh), it evolved to an [OpenHAB extension](https://www.openhab.org/addons/bindings/amazonechocontrol/) to integrate an Echo as a SmartHome Actor / Sensor. You browse those public implemententation to see, how they handle getting the credentials by a user login to reach those private api.

In the [Alexa extension](https://github.com/custom-components/alexa_media_player) of [Home Assistant Project](https://www.home-assistant.io), there is an [integration of the temperature endpoint](https://github.com/custom-components/alexa_media_player/pull/1244/commits/989a3d8a7a7a9e6a2d7555cd99e6db1f237b430e).

A summary of [reengineering of that endpoint](https://github.com/custom-components/alexa_media_player/issues/197) is:

- endpoint (TDL .de for German user): https://alexa.amazon.de/api/phoenix/state
- curl: `curl -H 'Cookie: x-amzn-dat-gui-client-v=1.24.205655.0; sid=; lc-acbde=de_DE; csrf=XXX; session-id-time=2082787201l; session-token="XXX"; session-id=XXX; ubid-acbde=XXX; x-acbde="XXX"; at-acbde="XXX"; sess-at-acbde="XXX";csrf=XXX' -H 'Accept: application/json; charset=utf-8' -H 'x-amzn-RequestId: XXX' -H 'User-Agent: PitanguiBridge/2.2.271281.0-[PLATFORM=Android][MANUFACTURER=Xiaomi][RELEASE=9][BRAND=Xiaomi][SDK=28][MODEL=MIX 3]' -H 'csrf: XXX' -H 'Accept-Language: de-DE' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' -H 'Host: alexa.amazon.de' --data-binary '{"stateRequests":[{"entityId":"AAA_SonarCloudService_XXX","entityType":"APPLIANCE"}]}' --compressed 'https://alexa.amazon.de/api/phoenix/state'`
- response:

> ```
> {
>     "deviceStates": [
>         {
>             "entity": {
>                 "entityId": "AAA_SonarCloudService_XXX",
>                 "entityType": ""
>             },
>             "capabilityStates": [
>                 "{\"namespace\":\"Alexa.TemperatureSensor\",\"name\":\"temperature\",\"value\":{\"value\":23,\"scale\":\"CELSIUS\"},\"timeOfSample\":\"2019-05-28T08:26:56.997Z\",\"uncertaintyInMilliseconds\":0,\"deepQuery\":true,\"timeOfStateChange\":\"\"}",
>                 "{\"namespace\":\"Alexa.AcousticEventSensor\",\"name\":\"glassBreakDetectionState\",\"value\":{\"value\":\"NOT_DETECTED\"},\"timeOfSample\":\"2018-12-10T05:28:01.283Z\",\"uncertaintyInMilliseconds\":10000,\"deepQuery\":true,\"timeOfStateChange\":\"\"}",
>                 "{\"namespace\":\"Alexa.AcousticEventSensor\",\"name\":\"detectionModes\",\"value\":{\"smokeAlarm\":{\"overallMode\":\"DISABLED\",\"cloudVerificationMode\":\"DISABLED\"},\"glassBreak\":{\"overallMode\":\"DISABLED\",\"cloudVerificationMode\":\"DISABLED\"}},\"timeOfSample\":\"2018-12-10T05:28:01.28Z\",\"uncertaintyInMilliseconds\":0,\"deepQuery\":true,\"timeOfStateChange\":\"\"}",
>                 "{\"namespace\":\"Alexa.AcousticEventSensor\",\"name\":\"smokeAlarmDetectionState\",\"value\":{\"value\":\"NOT_DETECTED\"},\"timeOfSample\":\"2018-12-10T05:28:01.283Z\",\"uncertaintyInMilliseconds\":10000,\"deepQuery\":true,\"timeOfStateChange\":\"\"}",
>                 "{\"namespace\":\"Alexa.ModeIndicator\",\"name\":\"securityMode\",\"value\":\"DISABLED\",\"timeOfSample\":\"1970-01-01T00:00:00Z\",\"uncertaintyInMilliseconds\":0,\"deepQuery\":true,\"timeOfStateChange\":\"\"}",
>                 "{\"namespace\":\"Alexa.AcousticEventSensor\",\"name\":\"overallMode\",\"value\":\"DISABLED\",\"timeOfSample\":\"2018-12-10T05:28:01.279Z\",\"uncertaintyInMilliseconds\":0,\"deepQuery\":true,\"timeOfStateChange\":\"\"}"
>             ],
>             "error": null
>         }
>     ],
>     "errors": []
> }
> ```

Credits for that work is to [Linus Dietz](https://github.com/Dielee) (and for the overall input [Alexander Noack](https://www.blogger.com/profile/03776828057013811695)) - I just collected it here.